# How to read the users from workitem-state in workflow workitem, RTC?

Tags: rtc

How do I read the users from workitem-state in workflow workitem, RTC?

I want to compare the logged in user with the current state users. Because I want to enable and disable the permissions depending upon the states.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a starting point, you can check out the question "[work item customization: getting current user as logged in user](https://jazz.net/forum/questions/133477/work-item-customization-getting-current-user-as-logged-in-user)".
It includes:

```
var getAuthenticatedContributor = com.ibm.team.repository.web.client.session.getAuthenticatedContributor; 
var loggedInUser = getAuthenticatedContributor().itemId;
```